# Как передать потоковый звук по WiFi через Arduino?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Имеется Arduino Uno, к ней присоединен WiFi модуль ESP8266, и микрофон. Гугл подсказал, что используя библиотеку RF24Audio можно оцифровать звук с микрофона и передать по WIFI. Но каким образом его потом обработать на ПК, что бы можно было слушать потоковое аудио? 
Существуют ли уже похожие проекты? Гуглил очень много, но ничего толко не нашел. Находил много проектов создания рации, но в них задйствуются две ардуино, а мне нужно что бы одна передавала звук, а на ПК уже прогаммного его обрабатывать.

Comment: какая ОС на ПК?

Comment: это не принципиально важно, можно установить любую, но в приоритете Windows 7

Comment: если не принципиально, то можно использовать возможности PulseAudio https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network

Answer (score 2):

У ESP8266 очень маленький битрейт для передачи аудио. Порядка 19200 бит в секунду по протоколу UDP.

Ардуино может оцифровывать звук с частотой 15625 Гц. То есть для передачи его по WiFi потребуется модуль с битрейтом не менее 125000 бод.

Comment: Ну допустим, что у нас есть телефония с ее 8 килогерцами, так почему бы и не слать в s16le в пакетиках? Можно даже полноценный RTP с uLaw на борту изобразить. Я просто с железками не работал никогда, может еще какие-то лимиты есть? Откуда этот "битрейт" берется?

Comment: 8000 Гц - это битрейт 64000 бод.

Comment: Просто Ардуино - микроконтроллер управления 3D-принтером. А ESP8266 предназначен для управления датчиками и сенсорами. Эти чипы не подходят для работы с мультимедиа.

Comment: А во что конкретно оно упирается? Может быть пожать можно как-то, если в трафик?

Comment: Алгоритмы сжатия требуют памяти и быстродействия. Вот, например, то, что подходит для данной задачи. https://www.arcturusnetworks.com/products/ucmk60-voip/